# Social Constructivism and Logical Necessity

Tags: logic, constructivism

I am after some kind of reading list on the topic of logical necessity and social constructivism. Any recommendations?

I'd like to be in a position to argue cogently that social constructivism can account for logical necessity.

Answer (score -1):

Although Wittgenstein is too subtle to be reduced to a ‘social constructivist’, you might start with his account of the “hardness of the logical must”. Dig up the dire Dummett paper on W’s philosophy of mathematics, and then Stroud’s response to it.